# Can a smart contract make calls (e.g. web service calls) to outside of the network?

Tags: legacy-protocol, smart-contract

Will IOTA smart contracts be able to make calls to external web services or other APIs, or is it too early to tell?

Comment: Any specific requirements?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the legacy-network and it is a good idea to keep only Shimmer/ShimmerEVM and latest IOTA Chrysalis questions

Answer (score -1):

We don't know if there will be something like Smart Contracts. I think you are referring to Q. It's, at the moment, just speculation. Maybe it is something like smart contracts, maybe it isn't. We will see.

IRI supports Extensions. So, theoretical you can implement your own protocol. But you need people who are willing to use this Extension. I also don't know exactly what the Extension interface supports.

/e But I know, for sure, that there is one company working on smart contract on the tangle. So there will be something. But maybe not from the foundation.

Comment: Q is probably not smart contracts.